# Real-time activity flow

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm maintaining and old PHP based CMS that contains forum software, an article publishing system, among other things - all custom. Now the owners want to implement a global, pseudo real-time (it'll probably just update once every ten seconds or something) activity flow, similar to the one on Facebook:

[image]

Right now I'm trying to think of the best and easiest way to implement this in such a way that it can be easily extended to include different kinds of activities (creating blog posts, commenting on photo albums/blog posts, creating or replying to forum threads, publishing articles, etc.)

The front-end bit shouldn't be too hard, **what I'm not sure about is how I should set up the events table to accommodate for all the different kinds of events that will be included.** All the events will include things like a user ID, a URL, a datetime and an "event type", but I would have to save very different data depending on whether a user created a photo album or if someone replied to a forum thread. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few approaches you could take with this depending on whether each users' view is unique or not - for example: can they flag certain things as not interesting to them, or do you want to hide items they've already read. (I'm assuming in this answer that all users see the same feed.)

I wouldn't use a separate events table to store "actions" for the following reasons:

- the information is only valid for a brief period of time (as long as it takes for an item to disappear off the top of the list) so you'd want to purge old values essentially creating a heavyweight FIFO buffer
- you'd be storing a duplicate of existing data in your system (i.e. a record that says news story X was created at Y time when the record for the news story already has a creation time on it)
- if an action is undone (or an item deleted) you would need to also delete the related entry in the events table
- different types of events will have different information and metadata making it hard to normalise them all into a single table schema

You could:

- run a scheduled script every 5 minutes or so that checks for any new activity (i.e. looks for new posts less than X minutes old) and writes a static HTML file with the activity feed contents that can be embedded in all pages where it should be visible
- write your activities into an in-memory store (i.e. memcache) as and when they occur and flush entries older that your maximum action age at the same time
- create a feed that fetches the latest action data on the fly but sits behind a proxy server that will cache it for a period of time... (this approach would also work well for per-user feeds)

**UPDATE: Original poster has confirmed that all users see the same feed contents. Based on that I would recommend the simpest solution is schedule a script that generates a static HTML file of the feed that can be embedded straight into the page where needed (as it doesn't require installing and configuring an in-memory store or a proxy server).**

Comment: Your assumption is correct. All users will see the same feed.

As for your recommended approaches:
1. That is similar to what I was thinking about doing, but the problem is that it wouldn't be anywhere near real-time. The client wants a nice slide-in effect whenever new stuff happens. Like I said in my post, it doesn't have to be _really_ real time, but at least kind of.

2. That sounds very interesting. I'll look into it.

3. Same problem as #1.

Very good answer though!

Comment: There is nothing stopping you generating the static file every minute if you wish (and the script is fast enough to make that a realistic option). Then with a couple of lines of Javascript you could refetch the static html file and embed into a container on the page.

Comment: Once every minute would still be far too slow. Once every 10 seconds would be acceptable. I have only just begun to check out memcached, but I figured I'd ask before I dig any deeper: would the stored values in memcached be global? So if User #1 creates a forum thread, I could push an object that represents that onto memcached, and then the next time the stream is refreshed for User #2, they would see that object?

Comment: @TommyBrunn - You shouldn't add auto-refresh like that. It'll overload your server. Look into AJAX and COMET like I suggested

Comment: @Tom - I know what AJAX and Comet are. I'm not going to implement it exactly like that. I was simply asking about the principle of it - whether the stored objects were available globally.

Comment: Every 10 seconds seems very fast. As a user I'd be pretty irritated if an area of the page was changing every 10 seconds! Also remember (as indicated by @Tom above) that EACH CONCURRENT user will be making a request every 10 seconds which won't scale beyond a couple of hundred users unless you have some serious kit!

Comment: @Tom using AJAX is no different - you'll still have to make a request to the server every X seconds to retrieve any changes. (Comet may be suitable however, but I've never used it so couldn't comment!)

Comment: @TommyBrunn Yes memcache runs as a service on the machine (not inside the web process managing the request). So all requests may interact with the same global store.

Comment: @JonathanWilliamson - As for the UX, I'll leave that to the designer. The scaling issue could be a problem, though. The site doesn't have massive traffic, but it's already somewhat strained, so I'd be nervous about introducing a huge performance hog like that.

Comment: @TommyBrunn then you'll have to be careful to rate-limit your requests to something the server can handle. But if you use the pre-generated HTML approach then at least all you're ever fetching is a single static file.

Comment: @JonathanWilliamson - No, using AJAX with Reverse AJAX or Comet is different. Read about it and you'll understand. Doing it any other way than HTTP push or some kind of reverse AJAX will overload your server